Why does my swiftUI screen get dismissed immediately?
I have been trying to implement the coordinator pattern following this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaLRST7tHFQ&t=917s
Currently this is my code
import SwiftUI

enum Page: String, Identifiable {
    case launch, dashboard, newContact, contactList

    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}

enum Sheet: String, Identifiable {
    case `default`

    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}

enum FullScreenCover: String, Identifiable {
    case `default`

    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}

protocol Coordinator: ObservableObject {

    func push(_ page: Page)

    func present(_ sheet: Sheet)

    func present(_ fullScreenCover: FullScreenCover)

    func pop()

    func popToRoot()

    func dismissSheet()

    func dismissFullScreenCover()
}

class AppCoordinator: Coordinator {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var sheet: Sheet?
    @Published var fullScreenCover: FullScreenCover?

    // MARK: - Builders

    // Launch
    let launchBuilder = Launch.Builder()
    let signInBuilder = SignIn.Builder()
    let signUpBuilder = SignUp.Builder()

    // Main
    let dashboardBuilder = Dashboard.Builder()
//    let newContactBuilder = NewContact.Builder()
//    let contactListBuilder = ContactList.Builder()

    // MARK: - Conformance: Coordinator

    func push(_ page: Page) {
        path.append(page)
    }

    func present(_ sheet: Sheet) {
        self.sheet = sheet
    }

    func present(_ fullScreenCover: FullScreenCover) {
        self.fullScreenCover = fullScreenCover
    }

    func pop() {
        path.removeLast()
    }

    func popToRoot() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }

    func dismissSheet() {
        self.sheet = nil
    }

    func dismissFullScreenCover() {
        self.fullScreenCover = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    @ViewBuilder
    func build(page: Page) -> some View {
        switch page {
        case .launch: self.launchBuilder.build()
        case .dashboard: self.dashboardBuilder.build(with: self)
        default: self.launchBuilder.build()
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func build(sheet: Sheet) -> some View {
        switch sheet {
        default: self.launchBuilder.build()
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func build(fullScreenCover: FullScreenCover) -> some View {
        switch fullScreenCover {
        default: self.launchBuilder.build()
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct AppCoordinatorView: View {

    @StateObject var coordinator: AppCoordinator = AppCoordinator()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
            coordinator.build(page: .launch)
                .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
                    coordinator.build(page: page)
                }
                .sheet(item: $coordinator.sheet) { sheet in
                    coordinator.build(sheet: sheet)
                }
                .fullScreenCover(item: $coordinator.fullScreenCover) { fullScreenCover in
                    coordinator.build(fullScreenCover: fullScreenCover)
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}

extension Launch {
    struct Builder: LaunchBuilder {
        
        // MARK: - Properties

        // MARK: - Conformance: Builder

        func build() -> some CRM_View {
            let useCases = Launch.UseCases()
            let viewModel = Launch.ViewModel(
                useCases: useCases
            )
            let view = Launch.View(viewModel: viewModel)

            return view
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

protocol LaunchView: CRM_View {
    
}

extension Launch {
    struct View: LaunchView {

        // MARK: - Properties

        let viewModel: Launch.ViewModel
        @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: AppCoordinator

        // MARK: - Views

        var body: some SwiftUI.View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Launch Placeholder")
                    Button {
                        viewModel.handle(event: .didAppear)
                        coordinator.push(.dashboard)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Hi")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

protocol LaunchViewModel: CRM_ViewModel {
    typealias ModuleEvents = Launch.Event
}

extension Launch {
    class ViewModel: LaunchViewModel {

        // MARK: - Properties

        let useCases: Launch.UseCases

        // MARK: - Lifecycle

        init(
            useCases: Launch.UseCases
        ) {
            self.useCases = useCases
        }

        // MARK: - Conformance: LaunchViewModel

        func handle(event: Launch.Event) {
            switch event {
            case .didAppear: 
                break
            case .willLoadData: break
            case .didLoadData: break
            }
        }
    }
}

I've got the dashboard module implemented in basically exactly the same way, just with the name change. I haven't implemented any functionality into any of these yet.
When I tap on the button on the launch view, it should route to the dashboard view, but it just dismisses immediately and I can't figure out why.

Although it might be good YouTube entertainment the Coordinator pattern just won’t work with SwiftUI’s declarative design where views are a function of state. Worth taking time to learn View structs, state and binding. You’ll also need to know computed vars to transform your states and connect bindings.

@ViewBuilder is for use only in a View, not in a class or outside of a View.
Re-think your approach, there are many official examples of how to manage data and view state.
See for example Managing model data in your app, for how to manage data in your app, and how to pass a model to other View. As mentioned the Coordinator pattern
is not appropriate for SwiftUI Views.

Thank you kindly
